# Problemas em carregar uma lista de Json no vue.js

Tags: vue.js

observe o código Javascript abaixo;

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        bancodedados:[]

    },
    methods:{

    },
    created:function(){
        var self = this;
            self.$http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/?format=json').then(function(response){
            /*console.log(response); */
            self.bancodedados = response.data;  
        });

    }


});
```

Essa é minha pagina;

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>nome</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="bancodedado in bancodedados">
                <td>{{ bancodedado.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.climate }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

O que está acontecendo é que ele está conseguindo carregar todas a lista porém não consigo visualizar como mostra abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talves o problema esteja no código html, somente preciso saber como corrigir;

====================================================================

veja o que aparece no meu consoles;

deu esse resultado com esse comando;

```
console.log(response);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso quer dizer que ele consegue carregar os registro do Json!

mas se for com esse comando;

consoles.log(this.bancodedados);

é bem diferente;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que aparece se voce der um `console.log(this.bancodeados)` ?

Comment: acabei de modificar minha postagem, poderia dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: o bancodedados precisa ter um json da resposta, pelo print do console, o json não está no response, mas sim no response.body. Tenta colocar dessa forma: `self.bancodedados = response.data.body;` e vê de da certo

Comment: Na verdade seria `self.bancodedados = response.body;`. Mas esse json não é uma lista/array como você espera, é um único objeto, com dados de só um planeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse url que tens só retorna um objeto. Usa outro que retorne uma array para poderes usar no `bancodedados`. Esse outro url tem uma array na propriedade `results`.

Exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bancodedados: []

  },
  methods: {

  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json').then(function(response) {
      self.bancodedados = response.body.results;
    });

  }


});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table td,
table th {
  display: table-cell;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Diametro</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="bancodedado in bancodedados">
        <td>{{ bancodedado.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ bancodedado.climate }}</td>
        <td>{{ bancodedado.diameter }} Km</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Pelo incrível que pareça estou seguindo vídeo aulas de uma instituição web, e percebo que você tem corrigido vários erros desse curso que estou fazendo, que coisa feia dessa instituição, ensinando com vídeo com códigos errados.   :P

Comment: @wladyband talvez seja para estimular nos alunos a descobrirem bugs? :) Mas se tem erros e o nível dos alunos ainda não chega para os corrigir  então é um problema.

Answer (score 0):

Voce esta usando errado, voce esta recuperando a resposta assim ... `response.data`, quando na verdade é `response.body`

Basta alterar essa linha `self.bancodedados = response.response.body;`

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zinuxemewe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: mesmo assim não pegou.

Comment: editei a resposta, tenta agora

Comment: o projeto é muito pequeno, você quer que eu coloco ele no github para dá uma olhada?

Comment: É melhor, porque se nao fica dificil ajudar

Comment: com essa nova alteração não house sucesso, ainda preciso de ajuda.

Comment: vou colocar no github, só um minuto, só queria fazer uma observação, ele é um projeto java, mas se você pegar ele e retirar a pagina principal e os arquivos javascript e css vai conseguir pegar fora do projeto java.

Comment: https://github.com/wladyband/vue/tree/master/vue/src/main/resources

Comment: Atualizei com o link do JSBin pra voce entender o que esta acontecendo, a questao eé o formato do retorno do seu json

Comment: teria que testar outro links de Json?

Comment: se for isso mesmo poderia me passar o link que você testou?

Comment: @wladyband Eu atualizei minha resposta com o link para voce testar